# Does the OWASP Zed Attack Proxy project have a list of all the vulnerabilities it tries to find/exploit?

Tags: owasp, zap, documentation

I'm trying to compile a list of vulnerabilities that ZAP tries to find when you run the "Active Scan" in ATTACK mode on a webapp. Does this list exist in the documentation anywhere? If it also has a list of all the inputs that it tries that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a FAQ for that :) https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQzaptests

ZAP has a built in set of 'input vectors' https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpUiDialogsOptionsAscaninput but you can also define your own via script input vectors: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpAddonsScriptsScripts

Comment: Perfect, thank you! However, still can't find the list of inputs it actually tries. For example, which queries specifically it tries to test for code injection.

Comment: Thats defined in the code :) e.g. https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/blob/master/src/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/ascanrules/CodeInjectionPlugin.java